# python time series country data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I have these columns within a csv and want to plot UK and France oranges in time series format.

I can plot for UK and Oranges in time series, but I cant plot UK + France oranges in time series.

Can someone help me?

Please look at picture attached for CSV
[Oranges_Apples_country.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXWnt.jpg)

```
import logging
import datetime
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#import orangesdata from CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('Oranges_Apples_country.csv')
df.head()
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date').head()

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['country', 'product', 'unit', 'date'])

df['country'] = ['UK', 'FRANCE']
df['product'] = ['ORANGES', 'APPLE']
df['unit'] = ['KG']
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far and explain exactly where you are stuck? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think we need a little more information in order ot help. What software are you using to plot the data?

Comment: Thank you - have posted the code above. I'm not sure if I am using the correct method. Should I be using df or an iloc type of code?

Comment: If your question is about subsetting, you can create a new DataFrame based on a subset of the first DataFrame. For example: `df2 = df[((df['COUNTRY'] == 'UK') & (df['PRODUCT'] == 'ORANGE')) | 
        ((df['COUNTRY'] == 'FRANCE') & (df['PRODUCT'] == 'ORANGE'))]
`

Answer (score 0):

Here some code to subset on the axes you mentioned. I took the `for` loop from another SO post, but I don't remember the link. Apologies to that contributor.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.read_csv('fruit.csv', parse_dates = ['DATE'])
df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
df2 = df[((df['COUNTRY'] == 'UK') & (df['PRODUCT'] == 'ORANGE')) | \
        ((df['COUNTRY'] == 'FRANCE') & (df['PRODUCT'] == 'ORANGE'))]

labels = []
for key, grp in df2.groupby(['COUNTRY', 'PRODUCT']):
    ax = grp.plot(ax = ax, y = 'QUANTITY')
    labels.append(key)
lines, _ = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

You can sum using `groupby.sum()`.

```
df3 = df2.groupby('DATE').sum()
df3.plot()
plt.show()
```